# Marshalling C# types to call a C++ IDispatch interface results in a type mismatch

Tags: c#, c++, com

I'm trying to call a c++ IDispatch interface with the following method definition:

```
ATL HRESULT TestFunc(long Command, [in, out] long* pData, [in, out] BSTR* pString, [out, retval] long* pRC);

// ...
Type t = Type.GetTypeFromProgID( "IMyTestInterfce" );
Object so = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
Object[] args = new Object[3];               
args[0] = -8017;
args[1] = 0;
args[2] = "";
Object result = so.GetType().InvokeMember("TestFunc", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, so, args);
```

The result from the call is a type mismatch but I'm not sure why.

> InnerException = {"Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))"}`

Thanks

Comment: @Ramhound I would normally but in this case I need to use late binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the second and third parameters (`pData` and `pString`) are marked as `[in, out]` in their definition, which means they translate to `ref` parameters in C#. You need to use [the overload of `InvokeMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3dhzwy.aspx) that accepts an argument of `ParameterModifier[]` to specify that those argument should be passed by reference, not by value. The array of `ParameterModifier` should contain one element that specifies the second and third indices to be `true` to notate that they are passed by reference.

```
ParameterModifier modifier = new ParameterModifier(3);
modifier[1] = true;
modifier[2] = true;

Object result = so.GetType().InvokeMember(
    "TestFunc",                           // name
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,            // invokeAttr
    null,                                 // binder
    so,                                   // target
    args,                                 // args
    new ParameterModifier[] { modifier }, // modifiers
    null,                                 // culture
    null                                  // namedParameters
);
```